# How to map the items from a list of records contained in an object to a unique array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of objects that contain an array as one of the values like so:

```
const obj_arr = [
{'key': ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-2', 'value-3']},
{'key': ['value-3', 'value-1', 'value-2', 'value-1', 'value-3']},
{'key': ['value-2', 'value-1', 'value-4', 'value-3', 'value-5']}
];
```

How do I take this list of values and map only the unique items to an array?

so far I have been able to do this:

```js
const obj_arr = [{
    'key': ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-2', 'value-3']
  },
  {
    'key': ['value-3', 'value-1', 'value-2', 'value-1', 'value-3']
  },
  {
    'key': ['value-2', 'value-1', 'value-4', 'value-3', 'value-5']
  }
];

let unique_arr = [...new Set(obj_arr.map(record => record['key']))];

console.log(unique_arr);

/*
let unique_arr2 = [...new Set(obj_arr.flatMap(record => record['key']))];
console.log('using guidance from Barmar: ', unique_arr2);
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

but this only gives me back each unique array like this:

```
unique_arr = [
['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-2', 'value-3'],
['value-3', 'value-1', 'value-2', 'value-1', 'value-3'],
['value-2', 'value-1', 'value-4', 'value-3', 'value-5']
]
```

what I actually need is this:

```
unique_arr = ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-4', 'value-5']
```

Comment: Use `.flatmap()` instead of `.map()` so the arrays will be merged.

Comment: do you have only a single property in each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the values of the objects and get a flat array for the constructor.

```js
const
    array = [{ key: ['value-1', 'value-2', 'value-3', 'value-2', 'value-3'] }, { key: ['value-3', 'value-1', 'value-2', 'value-1', 'value-3'] }, { key: ['value-2', 'value-1', 'value-4', 'value-3', 'value-5'] }],
    unique = [...new Set(array.map(Object.values).flat(Infinity))];

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the result you're looking for
here is a solution with reduce

```js
let uniqueArrReduce = [...new Set(obj_arr.reduce((acc, el) => [...acc, ...el.key], []) )]
```

with map and flat

```js
let uniqueArrMapFlat = [...new Set(obj_arr.map(el => el.key).flat())]
```